# What's the latest application of data on the twin cycle hypothesis?

Tags: type-2-diabetes

The [twin cycle hypothesis](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/781719_7) states that

> The accumulation of fat in liver and secondarily in the pancreas will lead to self-reinforcing cycles that interact to bring about type 2 diabetes. Fatty liver leads to impaired fasting glucose metabolism and increases export of VLDL triacylglycerol,[85] which increases fat delivery to all tissues, including the islets. The liver and pancreas cycles drive onward after diagnosis with steadily decreasing β-cell function. However, of note, observations of the reversal of type 2 diabetes confirm that if the primary influence of positive calorie balance is removed, then the processes are reversible.

What's the current application of that data to the management of type 2 diabetes in the community?